# label is not updating when using a delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, uistoryboardsegue

I have two viewController and iam using a delegate method to update a label in the first view controller with text entered in the second viewcontroller.

My problem is the value entered in the textfield(secondViewController) is not getting pushed into the UILabel(FirstVIewController)

My First ViewController.h

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <CustomDelegate>
@end
```

First ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController () 

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *infoLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)sendinfo:(NSString *)info
    {

_infoLabel.text = info;

    }

  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {

   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"info"])
      {
   SecondViewController *obj = segue.destinationViewController;

   obj.userDelegate = self;
      }

}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)sendinfo:(NSString *)info;

 @end

 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

 @property (weak, nonatomic) id <CustomDelegate> userDelegate;

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

SecondViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)sendInfo:(id)sender {


     [self.userDelegate sendinfo:_textField.text];
   UIViewController * controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
 }
```

Comment: what you want to do?? learn delegate or learn pass data??

Comment: Can you check that `self.userDelegate` is not nil and `_textField` is not nil and `_textField.text` is not nil? Is the delegate being set properly?

Comment: how u r moving from frist to second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating another UIViewController in your SecondViewController and the delegate is set to the viewController from where you are coming.

To see your changes, you should do a `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in your SecondViewController

Example:

```
- (IBAction)sendInfo:(id)sender {

  [self.userDelegate sendinfo:_textField.text];

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```